# Regular expression for spaces and integers, but no 'double negative' sign

Tags: java, regex

Trying to find a regex for a string containing only numbers and single spaces (but no spaces at beginning and end) such as this:

"1 2 3 -4" --> Accept

" 1 2 3 -4 " --> Not accept

So far been using this:

```
^\S+[-?\d ]*\b$
```

However this still accepts the string for:

"1  2 --3" which should not be accepted due to a double negative and a double space.

Note that the numbers can be any integer.

Any help?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code

```
^(?:-?\d+ )*(?:-?\d+)+$
```

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at beginning of the line
- `(?:-?\d+ )*` Match the following any number of times

  - `-?\d+` Match zero or one of the `-` character, followed by one or more digits, followed by a space character
- `(?:-?\d+)+` Match zero or one of the `-` character, followed by one or more digits
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
^-?\d+(?:[ ]-?\d+)*$
```

Note that

- the `+` quantifier is applied only to the `\d` expressions.
- I put the required single-space separator into a character class for clarity; it could equivalently be expressed without
- the anchors aren't really necessary if you are going to use `Matcher.matches()` to match single-line strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^\S+( (-?)[\d]+)+\b$
```

or even better:

```
^\S+( ((-?)\d+))+\b$|^\d$
```

in order to match single digits also

Edit (see comments):

This should be an even better version (removes that leading \S)

```
^\d( (-?)[\d]+)*\b$
```

Comment: Thank you. Nearly perfect, but this still accepts a negative sign with no attached number

Comment: I love how much you can fine-tune a regex :). Adding an optional - in front is not that hard: ^(-?)\d( (-?)[\d]+)*\b$